# Time comlexity is sqrt(n) but how did we obtained it?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

In first steps in algorithmic design and analysis I am following the book Algorithm Design by Kleinberg and Tardos I came across the Question/Case you can find down the page
the solution is indeed f(n) = sqrt(n). My concerns are :

1- Why I still find log(n) more acceptable .I still could not grasp the plus value from sqrt(n) even when it is said that we will use more jars / trials .

2- from where did we get the sqrt(n) ?. Using k jars (trials) I could think of n/k incrementation but then  lim n→∞ f(n) /n toward infinity is 1/k which is not 0. I got the feeling that the '2' in n^1/2 is tightly related to k = 2 , if yes how.

Thank you.

> Case: Assume that a factory is doing some stress-testing on various
> models of glass jars to determine the height from which they can be
> dropped and still not break. The setup for this experiment, on a
> particular type of jar, is as follows. You have a ladder with n rungs,
> and you want to find the highest rung from which you can drop a copy
> of the jar and not have it break. We call this the highest safe rung.
> It might be natural to try binary search: drop a jar from the middle
> rung, see if it breaks, and then recursively try from rung n/4 or 3n/4
> depending on the outcome. But this has the drawback that you could
> break a lot of jars in finding the answer. If your primary goal were
> to conserve jars, on the other hand, you could try the following
> strategy. Start by dropping a jar from the first rung, then the second
> rung, and so forth, climbing one higher each time until the jar
> breaks. In this way, you only need a single jar—at the moment it
> breaks, you have the correct answer—but you may have to drop it n
> times. So here is
> the trade-off: it seems you can perform fewer drops if you’re willing
> to break more jars. To understand better how this trade- off works at
> a quantitative level, let’s consider how to run this experiment given
> a fixed “budget” of k ≥ 1 jars. In other words, you have to determine
> the correct answer—the highest safe rung—and can use at most k jars in
> doing so. Now, please solve these two questions:
>
> 1. Suppose you are given a budget of k = 2 jars. Describe a strategy for finding the highest safe rung that requires you to drop a jar at
>    most f(n) times, for some function f(n) that grows slower than
>    linearly. (In other words, it should be the case that lim n→∞ f(n)/n =
>    0.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`log(n)` is the best time, but it requires `log(n)` jars.

If we are limited by 2 jars, we can apply sqrt-strategy.

Drop the first jar from some heights, forming sequence with **increasing** difference.

For differences `1,2,3,4...` we have heights sequence `1,3,6,10,15,21...`  (so-called triangle numbers). When the first jar is broken, we start from the `previous height+1`, with step 1, until the second one is broken.

If the first jar is broken at 15, we drop the second one using `11, 12, 13, 14` .

Such strategy gives `O(sqrt(n))` drops, because triangle number formula is `n~T(k)=k*(k+1)/2`, so to reach height above `n`, we should use about `k ~= sqrt(n)` tryouts, and less than `k` tryouts for the second jar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you gave a lead to look into, I mean from algebraic point of view I get it now. I just still have to understand if the key point is increasing differences then why exactly in the fashion of sqrt(n) ? and if n -> BigNumberButNotInfinity the n of jars will still be big in worst case when we have a broken jar but too far from returning back to the last safe step in the ladder or am I missing something here because I cannot dissociate the number of trials from number of jars ? I will dig some more .  but thanks anyway you already helped a lot.

Comment: `too far from returning back to the last safe step` we never go too far from the last step - distance to solution never exceeds sqrt(n) -  if we break the first jar at the height 1000000, we need about 1000 small steps more.

Comment: Instead of a triangle number as the step, if we use blocks of √n  as the step wouldn't that be better? e.g when we have 1000000, increasing our step by 1000?

Comment: @MaheshJamdade Constant step gives 2*sqrt(n) drops, while increasing step gives sqrt(2*n) drops